# How to insert hypen for birth date into date string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, append

How do I insert a hypen into a string like this 
01201997

and make it 01-20-1997

so far I have this

```
void datef(char string[])
{
    char strFinal[50];

    char *strB = "/", *strA[3]; // declare two strings you will join plus a third string to put in
    int x = 3; // declare integer to tell program how many characters you want to insert your string into
    int y = 5;
    strncpy(strFinal,string,x);// copies the first X characters into the strC, you have to add the null
    strFinal[x] = '\0'; // adds the null
    strcat(strFinal,strB); // copies the second half of the string
    strcat(strFinal,string+x); // another part to copy the remaining part of the string
    strncpy(strFinal, string, x);
    printf("%s\n",strFinal); // prints string
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `sprintf(strFinal, "%.2s-%.2s-%s", string, string + 2, string + 4);`?

Comment: Why does code use `char *strB = "/"`, yet title is "insert hypen"?  A hyphen is usually thought of as `'-'`.

Comment: Consider using `memmove` for the shifting

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/FnsXl7)